# How to enable auto-increment with Sql compact & C#

Tags: c#, auto-increment, compact-database

I'm using C# 2010 Express.

I have created a SQL Server CE database file (`.sdf`) then created Information table and ID, Name, City columns with Database Explorer. I want to save names and city user will write to the form. The auto-increment option is disabled in Database explorer and Properties windows. When I'm saving something to that database i must change the ID manually, how can I make ID column auto-increment enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way for SQL CE:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ALTER COLUMN ColumnName IDENTITY (/*seed*/1, /*increment*/1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but this code returned " The column cannot become an identity column after it is created. " exception

Comment: Hmmm, strange, it have to work for CE. Other way is to make a temp table, select all data to it, drop current table and recreate it with identity field. Or you can use Sql Management Studio, it will do all this for you automatically.