# How to make application auto-increment id in SQL Server Compact 3.5?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, sql-server-ce, auto-increment

I've set up a SQL Server Compact 3.5 database in my WinForm application. I set my ID identity to true so that when the user adds to the database it will automatically give it an ID and automatically increment it. However, for some reason after the first item is entered into the database the ID goes to -1 and then -2, -3, etc. How come it doesn't increment correctly? Did I set it up incorrectly?

Update:

[image]

Another Update: I ran the application and added 4 things to the database, closed the application and opened it again. When I did this all the id's were suddenly correct. It's like the id is only incorrect when when it's first added, but when the database is reloaded it's correct. Hopefully that made sense.

Comment: can you post your table structure.attached image on your post...let us see.

Comment: There you go. I've add the a screenshot of the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution in this thread:

[Negative Primary Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473215/negative-primary-keys)

Based on the information provided in that thread this occurs because I'm using a DataSet and a DataAdapter in my application.

Answer (score 3):

Edit your table schema and set `Identity Increment = 1` and `Identity Seed = 1` properties of `identity` column.

Comment: I've had that set and the problem still occurs.

Comment: @RandomlyKnighted Clean the project (Build  + Clean project). Basically WinForm app project copies the .sdf at `bin/debug`.

Comment: Just did a clean and build and tried it again. Still has the issue. This time it doesn't even start the first one at 1 it starts it at -1.

Comment: Script the CREATE TABLE statement in order to verify. How do you see that the value is -1 (DataGrid or SQL text output?)

Answer (score 1):

Check this site below:

[Is there any autoincrement type in SQL server CE?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/5276cb88-e756-4926-ad5d-32d68611054c/)

[How to enable auto-increment with Sql compact & C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052922/how-to-enable-auto-increment-with-sql-compact-c-sharp)

Comment: I tried the answer given in the 2nd link with no success. It still does the same thing. The identity is set to true. I've set it using both the designer and the via a query. Could there be something else keeping it from working correctly?